# How to create a release iteration (?) in TFS agile

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We are using VSTS for our project management, we have a single project setup with multiple teams (UI/Core/WebAPI etc...)
we completed our sprint and deployed our code. we would like now to start a new release. Is there a way to do that ?
It seems that we only have a single Iteration (the name of the project) and no way to create a new one.

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation on iterations?

Comment: I Did, I am unable to create a new iteration, do you mind pointing me to an article that explains how to do that please ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/set-iteration-paths-sprints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Project settings`, select `Work` tab (`https://xxxx.visualstudio.com/TeamProject/_admin/_work`), and create new iterations:

[image]